# PID of background task is different to the listed task PID using ps

Tags: linux, bash, pid, background-task

I have a strange issue, I can't quite get my head around. What I do is run a function called fn_rundumper which basically just calls the bash code:

```
pterm -z "cmd.sh" param1 &
```

Here is the output of that, which includes the background pid "27938858":

```
fn_rundumper
running fn_dumper...
[1] 27938858
fn_dumper...done
```

Then I look at the job numbers that are running this also shows PID "27938858":

```
jobs -l
[1] + 27938858 Running              $(pterm -z "$SCRIPTS_DIR/run_dumper.sh" $VO
```

Then I do a `ps` command to see what `pterms` are running:

```
ps | grep pterm
 24285189 ?        00:00:00 pterm
 27938859 ?        00:00:00 pterm
```

This yields the PID `27938859`. This is different to the others!

When I kill PID `27938858` nothing seems to happen. When I kill PID `27938859` then the background `pterm` is closed.

The problem is that I may want to run many different background pterms as well as some pterms that are not opened as background tasks (i.e. run separately). So when I come to tidy up I just want to close the pterms that I have opened via my script.

I was trying to use `jobs -l` to see the PIDs I need to close, but as I just described this is the wrong PID.

Can anyone explain why this happens? and also what I need to do to get the correct PID?
Thanks!

**- Edit1 -**

The best I can think of is to do a `ps | grep pterm` before and after and compare the results to find the new pterm PID... do-able, but ugly :(

**- Edit2 -**

I tested this again on the command line (no function call):

First I did:

```
`pterm -z "$VOE_SCRIPTS_DIR/run_dumper.sh" $PROJECT_DIR` &
```

And then looked at the `ps / $!` results and got the same behavior.

Then I did:

```
pterm -z "$VOE_SCRIPTS_DIR/run_dumper.sh" $VOE_PROJECT_DIR &
```

i.e. removed the back-ticks, now the PIDs all match up! I think I can remove the back-ticks from my code, but I don't really understand what that is all about!

Comment: "Nothing seems to happen" probably means you killed somebody else's `pterm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `$()` or backticks (command substitution) creates a subshell. So `27938858` is the PID of a subshell which in turn inkokes `pterm` with PID `27938859`.

Command substitution seems useless in your example, so you should just remove it.